# Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'org.dita.dost.util.StringUtils'

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm trying to debug an XSL transform using Visual Studio, but it keeps barfing on the clause:

```
xmlns:java="org.dita.dost.util.StringUtils"
```

This particular item is in the Dita OT library, which I have downloaded. I cannot find a way to "install" it or make it available to Visual Studio to let the XSLT go through.

-- Edit --

Of course it wasn't the mxlns line that was barfing, it was the first time it was used:

Running through another XSLT gives a similar error. In both cases it looks like Java can't find the namespace/class/JAR file.  I have very little experience with setting up Java (read "very little" as "none"). Is there something I need to do to make the JAR file visible to Java?

Comment: Given http://www.dita-ot.org/dev/user-guide/prerequisite-software.html I guess the toolkit is Java based and I suppose `xmlns:java="org.dita.dost.util.StringUtils"` is a way to extend XSLT 2.0 features calling into Java so I don't think you have any chance to run or debug the toolkit stylesheets in Microsoft Visual Studio with its .NET based XSLT 1.0 processor `XslCompiledTransform`.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered if that might be the case